# Redis lua script not working

Tags: lua, redis

I have created a redis lua script to execute a command based on key data type :-

```
local keyType = redis.call("TYPE", KEYS[1])
if (keyType == "string")
then
return redis.call("GET",KEYS[1])
else
return nil
end
```

It is returning null every time I am executing it.Can any please help in correcting the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The response to `redis.call` returns as a table that looks like this: `{"ok": "string"}` (if the type is a string of course)

So in order to properly check, you should change your code to:

```
local keyType = redis.call("TYPE", KEYS[1]).ok
```

and the rest of the code will work fine.

The issue is this: the TYPE command is one of the few commands that return a "simple string" or "status" redis reply (see the [redis protocol specs](http://redis.io/topics/protocol) for the response types). In the redis lua documentation it's stated that:

> Redis status reply -> Lua table with a single ok field containing the status

Which is what happened here.

Answer (score 0):

Using [1] will also work.local keyType = redis.call("TYPE", KEYS[1]) return keyType[1]