# Why does redigo return ERR unknown command 'EVALSHA'

Tags: go, redis

https://github.com/garyburd/redigo

**Why does redigo return error message?**

error message:

```
ERR unknown command 'EVALSHA'
ERR unknown command 'EVALSHA'
```

code:

```
const lockScript = `
local v = redis.call("GET", KEYS[1])
if v == false or v == ARGV[1]
then
    return redis.call("SET", KEYS[1], ARGV[1], "EX", ARGV[2]) and 1
else
    return 0
end
`

func CounterRegScript() {
    rc := RedisClient.Get()
    defer rc.Close()

    script := redis.NewScript(1, lockScript)
    resp, err := script.Do(rc, "xiaorui.cc", "nima", int64(3))
    fmt.Println(resp)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redis lua script not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315176/redis-lua-script-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of Redis. Upgrade to version 2.6 or later.